# using sourcepath in javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I want to create javadoc for my java file named `abc.java`
The sourcecode is placed in

```
C:/project1/src/
```

.It uses package `com.mypack` so class file is placed in

`C:/project1/src/com/mypack/` .

Now when I want to generate javadoc I run command from project1 directory as

```
javadoc -d ./src -sourcepath ./src
```

It shows No package or class specified

and when I run

```
javadoc -d ./src -sourcepath ./src com.mypack
```

It shows No sourcefile for package `com.mypack`

I know that sourcepath is used to give the location where sourcefile is placed so It should be give correct result with src only as sourcepath but It does not why???

But when I move abc.java to `project1/src/com/mypack` directory and now give source path as

```
javadoc -d ./src -sourcepath ./src com.mypack
```

Then It generates javadoc so Can you clear this doubt that When and how sourcepath is used in javadoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Java tools (javac, javadoc, the IDEs, etc.) expect Java source files and class files to be stored in a directory structure that matches exactly with the package structure. So, if your class is in the package `com.mypack`, the `.java` source file should be in `src/com/mypack`. Not in `src`.

You should also not store the .class files in the src directory (which is for source files). Use `javac -d ./classes` (for example) to make the compiler store `.class` files in a classes directory. And javac will automatically put your `.class` file under `classes/com/mypack`, to respect the package structure.

And do the same with javadoc: don't store the documentation in the src directory (which is for source files). Use javadoc -d `./doc` to make javadoc store the documentation in the `doc` directory.

Once you're comfortable with these conventions and tools, I recommend using a real build tool (like gradle or Maven, although I really prefer gradle), and to adopt their project layout conventions (they use the same one).